# Database design - should I normalise or denormalise (JOIN, or duplicate)

Tags: mysql, denormalization

I am creating a database with two main tables: `items`, `locations`.

The `items` table contains approx 3mill records and is rising at a rate of 1mill records a month.

The `locations` table contains 50,000 locations (name, latitude, longitude) and will not change in size.

Every read of the `items` table will require a `JOIN` to the `locations` table to find out where the item is located *unless* i duplicate the location content for every item record. I anticipate around 5mill queries to the items table every month.

Searching of the database will be performed by Sphinx, so I do not need to worry about complicates mysql geodistance queries.

My question is, would I be better off duplicating the locations data for every item, or perform JOIN statements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi James, there is a fairly good explanation of denormalisation and the hazard http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Denormalization.html

Comment: You can keep it normalised as the join will be performed on the primary key (assuming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better if you got a `JOIN` between `ITEM` and `LOCATIONS` with a foreign key in `ITEM`'s table.

There will be too many redundancies of data if you duplicate data for every tiem

Comment: Sounds good. I actually just performed a similar query on another one of our large databases (2mill records, 20,000 locations) and the different between a straight select and a join was really small. So I think I'm happy to go the normalised route

Answer (score 0):

We can discuss denormalisation from the academic point of view, but the practice always differs from theory. How you design your structure should also depend on the use - for you, I guess it's the responce time.

Joining to a 50k table is not very costly and will not take much time as long, as `location` size is not rising

If you have a plenty of free space, denormalisation will always improve your queries but needlessly duplicate 50.000 of records, on the other hand you will loose speed you are looking for.